# Is there a tradeoff between vocal flexibility and safety?

Tags: practice, voice

I would like to learn to sing, ideally with a large variety of textures.  In my googling, it seemed widely accepted that classical vocal styles were safer (reducing long term voice damage) than belting.

However, classical teachers also seem to strongly discourage pop singing, screaming, growling, etc.

While I realize that there may be some inherently dangerous textures, I'd rather not be constrained to operatic singing.  I don't plan on singing unamplified to a large crowd.

Is it possible to safely sing with a non-classical vocal technique?  Am I necessarily endangering my voice if I take belting lessons?

Comment: I realize I may be creating a false dichotomy between classical singing and belting.  The discussions I found online focused on belting vs classical, and I am unaware of any other techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most vocal styles can be performed without damage. The important thing is to listen to what the body tells you. If you get a lot of pain with some technique, sore throat for long time intervals etc., then this will be damaging in the long run.

A lot of people, me included, have been using "dangerous" techniques like screaming and growling for decades without issues.

That being said, nothing is entirely safe. Even people using the recommended techniques can get issues in the long run. Risk is involved in all we do, picking up an instrument might lead to problems with tendons and so on. I'm trying to say that close to all techniques can be used without a significant risk of damage.